# My any-dice program times out, when calculating large limit break checks

Tags: anydice

[Someone](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55180453#55180453) in chat helped write [an anydice program](https://anydice.com/program/1d26f) to calculate limit breaks in an RPG I'm developing, but after making some changes, it times out for dicepools > 7.

The system I have in mind, is that if any of the dice you roll is below a threshold, you can bank the sum of all failed rolls for later use, by converting it into a limit break token (currently, at an exchange rate of 1:4). I'm toying with requiring a certain number of successes before you can convert failed, which may or may not be slowing down the program.

```
function: sum X:s less than L with at least K successes {
  R: 0
  S: 0
  loop I over X {
     if I <= L { R: R + I }
     if I > L { S: S + 1 }
  }
  if S >= K { result: R/4 }
  if S < K { result: 0 }

}
```

Is there a more efficient way of running this program? Initially before my tweaks, the same helpful person suggested this as an alternative to the function: `output 3d{1..6, 0:6} named "Alt dice"` but I can't figure a way of running that, which is probably less likely to time out, and still check for a minimum number of successes.

Here is the code that causes the time out:

```
output [sum 1d12 less than 7 with at least 0 successes] named "1 die limit break"
output [sum 2d12 less than 7 with at least 1 successes] named "2 die limit break"
output [sum 3d12 less than 7 with at least 1 successes] named "3 die limit break"
output [sum 4d12 less than 7 with at least 1 successes] named "4 die limit break"
output [sum 5d12 less than 7 with at least 1 successes] named "5 die limit break"
output [sum 6d12 less than 7 with at least 1 successes] named "6 die limit break"
\Times out around here\
output [sum 7d12 less than 7 with at least 1 successes] named "7 die limit break"
output [sum 8d12 less than 7 with at least 2 successes] named "7 die limit break"
output [sum 9d12 less than 7 with at least 2 successes] named "7 die limit break"
output [sum 10d12 less than 7 with at least 2 successes] named "7 die limit break"
```

I found the timeout point by running each line individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an even more efficient way to do this than [Someone_Evil's solution](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/174075).  It's based on the observation that the result of each failed roll is uniformly distributed between 1 and \$L\$, where \$L\$ is highest roll that counts as a failure.

Thus, we can do the calculation in stages: first we figure out how many failures there are, and then we roll that many \$L\$-sided dice to represent the failed rolls, and sum the results.  Or, in more detailed steps:

1. Determine the probability of each single roll failing.  This is simply \$L \mathbin/ 12\$ (for 12-sided dice); in AnyDice, this is most conveniently represented with the expression `d12 <= L`, which returns a die that rolls \$1\$ with probability \$L \mathbin/ 12\$ and \$0\$ otherwise.
2. Determine the distribution of the number of failed rolls out of \$N\$, which is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters \$n = N\$ and \$p = L \mathbin/ 12\$.  In AnyDice, this distribution is conveniently obtained with the expression `Nd(d12 <= L)`.
3. Modify the distribution obtained in the previous step so that values greater than \$N - K\$ (corresponding to less than \$K\$ successes out of \$N\$) are replaced with \$0\$ (since we will sum no failed rolls in that case).  In AnyDice, this can be easily done with a helper function like this:

   ```
   function: X:n if at most Y:n else Z:n {
     if X <= Y { result: X }
     else { result: Z }
   }

   X: [Nd(d12 <= L) if at most N-K else 0]
   ```
4. Output the sum of \$X\$ \$L\$-sided dice, where \$X\$ is distributed according to the modified binomial distribution from the previous step.  In AnyDice, we can simply obtain this sum as `XdL` (or, writing out the definition of `X` from above, as `[Nd(d12 <= L) if at most N-K else 0]dL`).

Putting these all together, [here's the full program](https://anydice.com/program/1d2b2):

```
N: 8  \ total number of dice in pool \
L: 7  \ highest failing roll \
K: 1  \ minimum number of successes needed \

function: X:n if at most Y:n else Z:n {
  if X <= Y { result: X }
  else { result: Z }
}

X: [Nd(d12 <= L) if at most N-K else 0]
output XdL / 4 named "(sum of [N]d12 at most [L]) / 4 with at least [K] successes"
```

Of course you can also [wrap this code in a loop](https://anydice.com/program/1d2b3) or even [in a function](https://anydice.com/program/1d2b1).

Comment: That's very clever

Answer (score 6):

Let's first recognize what we need to do with the dice pool:

- We want to sum all the values <= 7
- Count the number of values > 7

This means we only need the dice to include the 1 to 7 part, and can let the other entries be zero and count those. This means we don't need a loop with a test to sum, we can just let anydice use the built in sum which happens on artimetic operation on a sequence. We thus replace the d12 with `{1..7, 0:5}`. We can also test 0 very simply by using the boolean behaviour of sequences.

Implementation ([Anydice link](https://anydice.com/program/1d272)):

```
DIE: {1..7, 0:5}

function: sum X:s with at least K successes {
  S: X = 0
  if S >= K { result: X/4 }
  else { result: 0}
}

output [sum 8dDIE with at least 1 successes] named "8 die limit break 2 success"
```

A downside to this method is that you need to set up the threshold in the die constructor, though it should be possible to create a constructor for it, if desirable.

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91446/syntax-for-a-unique-dice-system-on-anydice/91479#91479 seems relevant to constructing die, so no need to add it to this answer.